# Dynamically adding css files to head (priority reversed in IE)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I'm adding .css files with javascript to the head and order them with the highest priority last and the least prioritized first.

Like:

```
base.css
theme.css
responsive.css
```

And this works fine with every browser I've tried apart from IE (I've tested IE8,9 and 10) but If I reverse the order:

```
responsive.css
theme.css
base.css
```

It works in IE(8,9,10) but that doesn't work in every modern browser.

Is there any IE priority bug? If I statically add the files without the problem, so it seams to be a javascript problem but just for IE.

Anyone know about this problem or even a solution?

Comment: Could we see the css files? if it's not the media queries then it should be something in the css which is unsupported by IE and it's breaking the theme. @Vincent_Hogendoorn's solution seems good, but you should track down the problem source I guess.

try to validate the css files through any online validator, it might give you clues about what's happening

Answer (score 0):

One solution is first check with javascript what kind of browser there's used.

```
BrowserDetect.browser
```

And after that use an if-else statement..

```
if(IE){
  responsive.css
  theme.css
  base.css
}
else{
  base.css
  theme.css
  responsive.css
}
```

Comment: I've thought about this to, but feels like a last resort. But is still a solution.

Good suggestion anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's because older versions of IE don't understand media queries, which are used in the responsive design, I guess in your responsive.css you have things like `@media screen and (min-width: 960px)`.

Normally conditional comments are used to detect if the current browser is IE (and it's version) and load a css file or not.

Personally I like the mobile first philosophy when doing responsive design, there's a sample tutorial: http://gomakethings.com/mobile-first-and-internet-explorer/

This is called **Progressive Enhancement**. Doing the css for the simplest platform first, and adding up things for the newer browser.

If you want options there is another practice called **Graceful Degradation**, which is the opposite, having the full featured CSS and ignoring / removing those features for the older browsers.

You should google a bit about both those practices to understand them better if you really want to do clean and good responsive design

Comment: Thank you for taking your time, I can assure you that it's not that media query is unsupported. The problem appears in all versions of IE even 9 and 10.

The problem is also that the theme style is not applied.

Answer (score 0):

There must be another problem somewhere, because IE and other browsers do not differ in the way they cascade style sheets. Please create a JSfiddle.

Comment: What you mean IE and other browsers do not differ in the way they cascade style sheets? That's been a problem since the browsers were born, all the hacks people had to find to make css effects similar in different browsers...

Comment: Yes, but not because of how browsers prioritize that cascading order.